# Metric spaces and σ-closure-preserving bases (Nagata's metrization theorem)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image: Nagata's metrization theorem]

The first two line of the proof say that if $X$ is metrizable (so paracompact) then clearly there is a base $\mathcal{G}= \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} G_i$ having this property. Paracompactness just gives locally finite open refinement for any open cover of $X$. So could you please tell me how I find such a base?

(The image above is from Harold W. Martin, *A note on the Frink metrization theorem*, Rocky Mountain J. Math., Vol.6, No.1 (1976), pp.155-157, [doi:10.1216/RMJ-1976-6-1-155](http://dx.doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-1976-6-1-155).)

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $\mathscr{G}_n$ be a locally finite open refinement of the open cover

$$\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in X\right\}\;.$$

Locally finite families are closure-preserving, so each $\mathscr{G}_n$ is closure preserving. Let $x\in X$ and $n\in\Bbb Z^+$; then $\{G\in\mathscr{G}_n:x\in G\}$ is finite, so $V_n(x)=\bigcap\{G\in\mathscr{G}_n:x\in G\}$ is an open nbhd of $x$. Fix any $G_x\in\{G\in\mathscr{G}_n:x\in G\}$; then $G\subseteq B\left(y,\frac1n\right)$ for some $y\in X$, so

$$\operatorname{diam}V_n(x)\le\operatorname{diam}G_x\le\operatorname{diam}B\left(y,\frac1n\right)\le\frac2n\;.\tag{1}$$

Thus, for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ we have

$$x\in V_{3n}(x)\subseteq B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\;,$$

and $\{V_n(x):n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is therefore a local base at $x$.

**Added:** Let $\mathscr{G}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\mathscr{G}_n$. The fact that $\mathscr{G}$ is a base for $X$ also follows easily from $(1)$: for any $G\in\mathscr{G}_{3n}$ we have

$$x\in G\subseteq B\left(x,\frac1n\right)\;.$$

Comment: What is the basis for X here? Are you claiming that $\mathcal{G}=\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{G}_{i}$ will be required basis for X.   But I suppopse this might not basis for X.

Comment: @Manik: Yes, $\mathscr{G}$ is a base for $X$. I thought that that was pretty clear, so I didn’t mention it, but I’ll add it now.

Comment: from your construction $\mathcal{G}=\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mathcal{G}_{i}$ is a $\sigma$-locally finite open refinement for your open cover $\{(x, \frac{1}{n}) : x\in X\} $ [which you taken as a base]. But this need not imply that $\mathcal{G}$ is also base. So we can't take $\mathcal{G}$ as a base.

Comment: @Manik: What I just added to my answer proves that it’s a base.

Comment: No no, I just want to know that where from you are taken the fact that $\mathcal{G}$ is a base for X?? This line I am not getting.

Comment: @Manik: It shows that if $x\in X$, and $U$ is any open nbhd of $x$, then there is a $G\in\mathscr{G}$ such that $x\in G\subseteq U$. That’s exactly what it means for $\mathscr{G}$ to be a base for $X$.

Comment: for each $x\in X$ and open U if you find $G \in \mathcal{G}$ s.t $x\in G \subseteq U$ then this may not be base. You need to check other condition if $x\in U_1 \cap U_2$ then there exists U s.t $x\in U \subseteq U_1 \cap U_2$. So $\mathcal{G}$ not necessarily a base.

Comment: @Manik: That condition is an immediate consequence of what I’ve already proved. (And if you’re advanced enough to be looking at metrization theorems, you should already know several equivalent conditions for a family $\mathscr{B}$ to be a base for a topology $\mathscr{T}$. One is the condition that I stated. Another is that $\mathscr{T}$ is the set of all unions of subfamilies of $\mathscr{B}$. And yet another is the pair of conditions that you appear to be familiar with.)